# URL Shortener/Redirect going to an undefined page

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a URL Shortener for the website Scratch, the intended functionality is that if you navigate to a certain URL on my website (gobo.cf) it will take you to a certain project page.

For Example: If you go to http://gobo.cf/?to=165451669 it *should* redirect to  https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/165451669/ but instead, it goes to https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Gobo Redirect</title>
<script>
   var projectid = window.location.hash.split('?to=')[1]
   console.log(projectid)
   var redirect = "https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/" + projectid
   console.log(redirect)
</script>
</head>
<body onload="window.location = redirect;">
</body>
```

I have tried a number of solutions but whatever I try it always ends up redirecting to https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/undefined.

Comment: Your starting with `window.location.hash` but there's no hash in the url so that just returns undefined. Maybe you want `window.location.search.split('?to=')`

Comment: If you want you can take a look at this component I built to deal with query strings easily, it might be useful here and in the future. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196926/extending-window-location-give-access-to-query-string-elements/196989

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `hash` item in the location object. Hash is used when your URL looks like `https://gobo.cf/foo#bar?to=12345` (note the `#` character). If you use `search` (or `href`), you'll have better results, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gobo Redirect</title>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      // You can open Chrome inspector to "debug" and set breakpoints                                                    
      // and can change this variable to help out with that.                                                             
      var slowItDown = true;

      function doRedirect() {
          var hash = window.location.hash;
          console.log( "Oh no, hash is empty!:", hash );
          var search = window.location.search;
          console.log( "Search is: ", search );
          var projectid = search.split('?to=')[1];
          console.log(projectid);
          var redirect = "https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/" + projectid;
      console.log(redirect);
      }

     </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="slowItDown ? setTimeout( doRedirect, 10000 ) : doRedirect();">

  </body>
</html>
```

The code I added in the onload will wrap your redirect in a function that gets called after 10 seconds so you could put a breakpoint inside chrome console and step through it. You can change the `slowItDown` variable to enable or disable that and give yourself time to set the breakpoint the first time.